# change the label text using jquery and json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am havind a local JSON where i am trying to change the text of the label based on teh node id. I am very new to js and json. Please need a help learning from the basics.

JSON:

```
{
"Collection":
        [
            {"categoryId": 1, 
                "cList" :  [
                    {"NodeId": 1, "name": "a", },
                    {"NodeId": 2, "name": "b", },
                    {"NodeId": 3, "name": "c", },
                    {"NodeId": 4, "name": "d", },
                    {"NodeId": 5, "name": "e",}
                ]
            },

        ],
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><label></label></div>
```

I have a field called nodeId in my JSON, it have some unique id value. the labels should be five in number in my html which should be dynamic and each label should have corresponding json text

Comment: So, in this case, the `label` would get which text exactly (and why)? And what *exactly* are you having problems? Surely you are not asking us to implement the complete solution to parse the JSON and update some DOM elements?

Comment: you might wan to start here https://angularjs.org

Comment: _Based on NodeId the corresponding text should appears for label_....this is bit confusing what exactly you want? better if you post your expected result.

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct use of [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the labels should be five in number in my html which should be dynamic
>   and each label should have corresponding json text

You may try something like this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ9U6/1/)):

```
var nodes = $obj.Collection[0].cList;
$('label').each(function(k, v){
    $(this).text(nodes[k].name);
});
```